# How to use coroutine that includes http request?

Tags: unity-game-engine, httprequest, coroutine, yield-return

I have a unity scene. It gets an image using http requests and shows them each two seconds. The order of these images is important. So, steps of the program :

1. Get an image using http request
2. Show it, update index counter
3. Go to the step 1

My code is here :

```
  int counter = 0;
  float tempTimeLimit = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        if (tempTimeLimit > 1)
        {
            // Decrease timeLimit.
            tempTimeLimit -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(_Refresh());
            tempTimeLimit = timeLimit;
        }    
    }

    IEnumerator _Refresh ()
    {
        if (counter < 19)
        {
            counter += 1;
            ......    
            var req = new WWW(url);

            yield return req;

            byte[] data = req.texture.EncodeToPNG();
            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../" + counter + ".png", data);

            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = req.texture;

        }
    }
```

I expect that I see 19 png files. But I see only 8-9-10 files.[Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) says that

> This will wait until the coroutine has finished execution.

So I expect that my code should works succesfully but doesn't.

**EDIT**

I define a variable as a flag. I intialize and control it for waiting. It works for me.

```
void Update()
{
        if (!wait)
        {
            wait = true;
            StartCoroutine(_Refresh());
            counter ++;
        }
}
IEnumerator _Refresh ()
{
    if (counter < 19)
    {
        ..........
        var req = new WWW(url + "?" + qs);
        yield return req;
        if (req != null)
           wait = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You said you expect 19 png files, so this means that you need to get image and show it every 2 seconds 19 times? Are these image from the-same link or are you downloading the-same image 19 times? What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is the strangest code I have seen in my life

Comment: **IMPORTANT** you ABSOLUTELY MUST USE **Application.persistentDataPath**.  This is an incredibly confusing thing about Unity.  (1) you must - always - everywhere - only - use **Application.persistentDataPath**  Nevertheless (2) Unity mentions other paths in the doco.  But (3) **see point 1**.

Comment: @Programmer The content of url string is different each time. It has 19 different query. I didin't write into wuestion text because this part is not important for now, I

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You have a new solution from Joe and you haven't told him if it works or not. Try that first. If it doesn't then I will provide my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong from few points of view, but most important is you have no guaranty that fetching image will be done in given time. Try something like this:

```
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(_Refresh());
    }

    IEnumerator _Refresh ()
    {
        counter = 0;
        while (counter < 19)
        {
            counter += 1;
            ......    
            var req = new WWW(url);

            yield return req;

            byte[] data = req.texture.EncodeToPNG();
            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../" + counter + ".png", data);

            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = req.texture;

        }
    }
```

Comment: To run only start function is not enough for me.I need it at runtime many times.